# VBA json extract all data by a specific property name

Tags: json, excel, vba

I use VBA JSON parser from https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser

I have the following json:

```
{
   "Porp1": {
      "Prop2": {
        "name": "test"
      },
   },
   "name": "test123",
   "other_prop": {
     "name": "specific name"
   }
}
```

with that tool I need to extract all values from `name` fields.

For now I use the follwing code:

```
Dim vJson As Object
Dim sState As String
JSON.Parse response, vJson, sState

'From here don't know to extract all `name` properties, no matter of level of nesting
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A converted JSON is a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) that contains properties. The keys are the property names, the values can be

- simple values (eg strings)
- Dictionaries.
- Arrays (either of values or Dictionaries)

So the easiest way to travel thru the JSON is to create a recursive routine.

If the property is a simple value, check the property name. If the property name = `"name"`, write the property *value* (or do whatever you want to do)

If the property is a Dictionary, make a recursive call the the routine.

If the property is an Array, loop over that array and check if the members are again Dictionaries. If yes, make a recursive call for every member.

The following routine does exact that. I added a "Prefix" parameter so that you can see where the value came from.

```
Sub findProperty(prefix As String, jsonDict As Variant, lookForProperty As String)

    Dim propertyName As Variant
    Dim childJsonDict As Dictionary
    
    For Each propertyName In jsonDict.Keys
        If isDictionary(jsonDict(propertyName)) Then
            Set childJsonDict = jsonDict(propertyName)
            findProperty prefix & IIf(prefix = "", "", ".") & propertyName, childJsonDict, lookForProperty
        ElseIf IsArray(jsonDict(propertyName)) Then
            Dim i As Long
            For i = LBound(jsonDict(propertyName)) To UBound(jsonDict(propertyName))
                If isDictionary(jsonDict(propertyName)(i)) Then
                    Set childJsonDict = jsonDict(propertyName)(i)
                    findProperty prefix & IIf(prefix = "", "", ".") & propertyName & "[" & i & "]", childJsonDict, lookForProperty
                End If
            Next i
        ElseIf LCase(propertyName) = LCase(lookForProperty) Then
            Debug.Print prefix & IIf(prefix = "", "", ".") & propertyName, jsonDict(propertyName)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function isDictionary(property As Variant) As Boolean
    If VarType(property) <> vbObject Then Exit Function
    isDictionary = TypeName(property) = "Dictionary"
End Function
```

You can call this from your code with

```
Dim vJson As Object
Dim sState As String
JSON.Parse response, vJson, sState
If TypeName(vJson) = "Dictionary" Then
    Call findProperty("", vJson, "Name")
Else
    MsgBox "Error parsing JSON"
End If
```

And the output in the immediate window is

```
Porp1.Prop2.name            test
name          test123
other_prop.name             specific name
```

**Update**
a) There was an issue with my code (stupid Cut&Paste error) handling arrays, corrected.

b) The JSON converter expects a Variant as result variable (vJson). If you declare it as Object or Dictionary, the converter will raise a runtime error when the JSON-Code is invalid (as you can't assign a scalar like `Null` to an Object). I changed the code accordingly.

c) This code will not work if the topmost element is an Array, it expects a Dictionary. Hope that fits for you, I neither have the time nor valid test data to rewrite it.

Comment: Note that JSON is case-sensitive, so you should compare `propertyName` in a case-sensitive manner. Also the code could perhaps be made more DRY by `prefix = prefix & IIf(prefix = "", "", ".") & propertyName` at the start of the `For Each` loop.

Comment: I get error `Object variable or With block variable not set`, cant' figure out where, VBA editor sucks, it doesn't show line number where error occur

Comment: Seems that `childJsonDict` is not defined when breakpoint is in `For` loop of `IsArray` condition

Comment: VBA editor usually doesn't suck. Go to Tools -> Options -> General Tab and check "Break in Class modules", or "Break on All Errors". For the rest: See my update.